# MVC Asynchronous Ajax Calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an eCommerce website and I have the following template:

```
<div class="product-box">
    Product 1
</div>

<div class="product-box">
    Product 2
</div>

<div class="product-box">
    Product 3
</div>
```

The website is ASP.NET MVC, I want to fill the different product box with product information asynchronously using jQuery ajax calls to my MVC controller, what is the best way to do it?

I can already think of something like that

```
<div id="product1" class="product-box">
    Product 1
</div>

<div id="product2" class="product-box">
    Product 2
</div>

<div id="product3" class="product-box">
    Product 3
</div>

<script>
$.get("/GetProductInfo/1", {}, function (data) {
    $("#product1").html(data);
});

$.get("/GetProductInfo/2", {}, function (data) {
    $("#product2").html(data);
});

$.get("/GetProductInfo/3", {}, function (data) {
    $("#product3").html(data);
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't make sense and is not the best way to do it. Imagine I have 1000 products, madness. Anybody can advice the best way I can achieve this?

Comment: What triggers the loading of the details into a div? If you want to load then all at once, why not just return a view that displays all the items details including the `div`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using pure ASP.NET MVC using [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Invokes the specified child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

Example code:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetProductInfo", "YourController", new { id: YourProductId });}
```

---

If you want to perform same opertaing using jQuery, I would recommend you to use custom `data-` prefixed attributes to store product id.

Here is an example using [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [**.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

*HTML*

```
<div data-productid="1" class="product-box">
    Product 1
</div>

<div data-productid="2" class="product-box">
    Product 2
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$('.product-box').each(function(index, element) {
    $.get("/GetProductInfo/", {
        id: $(element).data('productid')
    }, function(data) {
        $(element).html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

#### HTML:

you can use `data-*` attribute to provide product numbers like:

```
<div data-id="1" class="product-box">
<div data-id="2" class="product-box">
<div data-id="3" class="product-box">
.......
// more
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.product-box').each(function(){
        var dataID = $(this).data('id');
        $.get("/GetProductInfo/" + dataID, {}, function (data) {
             $("#product"+dataID).html(data);
        });
    });
});
```